# Api Key Quota for different resources in API Gateway AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, rest, aws-api-gateway

I want to give my customer just one api key that he can use for different resources inside the api gateway, the problem is that the usage plans are for the whole api gateway and I want to set different amounts for each resources for example:

- Endpoints aaa/resource1 - can be called 100 times
- Endpoints aaa/resource2 - can be called 40 times
- Endpoints aaa/resource3 - can be called 200 times

From what I have seen this cannot be achieved with the usage plan. I would have to set different api and set the usage plan per each of these and share the api key between all of them but that would be to much setup so Im pretty sure theres a better way.
I have thought of using a DB to see how much times he has used each resource.

Comment: i think you might can do a separate stage per plan, rather than a separate API, im faced with a similar requirement tho, and also having trouble finding any information

Comment: I was thinking of doing the same but in theory that would be a lot of management, I would think there is a better way

Comment: In talking with an experienced architect, it appears the design is to have multiple plans, as much as one per resource depending on your granularity.

Comment: Oh wow, that would make it hard to mantain but it does seem to be the only way. Thank you